# what does "pants-droppingly" mean?

Tags: meaning

> **Clue #2:** He’s making 10 sales a month. Even if I wrote *pants-droppingly* good copy for him and increased his sales by 200% — a % lift any CRO expert would blog & tweet about — this would only generate an extra $200 per month for his business:

what does "pants-droppingly" mean?

Comment: It means "astoundingly" or "surprisingly".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What would it take to get you to drop your pants (undo your belt and let them fall to the floor)?  Imagine that.  That is how good the copy is.  So good, it will make you drop your pants.  Amazingly good.

Edit:  This expression does have "mature" roots, but it is commonly used in scenarios where the speaker is not meaning to intentionally allude to what happens after the pants go down. It is informal, and mildly risque.

Comment: Although this answer has been accepted by the OP, it is simply incomplete and inferior to the one given by @A.Beth. It is vital, in order to understand when use of the phrase is or is not appropriate, to be clear about *why* said pants will be dropped. As A.Beth says, the reason is sexual which means that "pants-droppingly" could be seen as a taboo phrase in some situations. For example, it would not be appropriate for a school teacher to use it when teaching children.

Answer (score 3):

In the US, "pants-droppingly" would tend to have "mature" connotations -- e.g., writing something so good about someone that people would drop their pants because they wanted to go to bed with him. (Or her.)

(...this was asked at [Meaning "pants-dropping"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/47816/meaning-of-jaw-dropping-and-pants-dropping) , wasn't it?)